# Compare tensorflow model architecture for unit test

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, pytest, tensorflow2.0

What would be the best way to compare two models architecture in tensorflow for unit test ?

I would like to test that my models contains the same layers, with the same configuration.

I would also like to test that one model with custom block is similar to a model without custom block.
For example:

```
filters = 64
kernel_size = 3
pool_size = (2, 2)
activation = "relu"
padding = "same"
kernel_initalizer = "he_normal"

inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input((64, 64, 3))
conv2d_1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters,
                                   kernel_size,
                                   activation=activation,
                                   padding=padding,
                                   kernel_initializer=kernel_initalizer)(inputs)
conv2d_2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters,
                                   kernel_size,
                                   activation=activation,
                                   padding=padding,
                                   kernel_initializer=kernel_initalizer)(conv2d_1)
pool1 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=pool_size)(conv2d_2)

my_seq_separated = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=pool1)
```

Should be tested similar to

```
class UnetContractiveLayer(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self,
                 filters: int,
                 kernel_size: int,
                 pool_size: Tuple[int],
                 n_convolution_layer: int = 2,
                 activation: str = "relu",
                 padding: str = "same",
                 kernel_initalizer: str = "he_normal",
                 **kwargs):
        super(UnetContractiveLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.class_name = "UnetContractiveLayer"

        # Convolution layers are all similar, we can build them with a list
        self.conv_layer = [
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters,
                                   kernel_size,
                                   activation=activation,
                                   padding=padding,
                                   kernel_initializer=kernel_initalizer) for _ in range(n_convolution_layer)
        ]

        self.pool = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=pool_size)

    def call(self, input_tensor, training=False):
        x = self.conv_layer[0](input_tensor)

        for conv_layer in self.conv_layer[1:]:
            x = conv_layer(x)

        x = self.pool(x)

        return x

    def get_config(self):
        # config = tf.keras.layers.Layer.get_config()
        """
        Do something here to return individual layer config
        """
        config = tf.keras.layers.Layer.get_config(self)
        
        config["layers"] = []
        for layer in self.layers:
            config["layers"].append(layer.get_config())
        return config

inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input((64, 64, 3))
unet_layer = UnetContractiveLayer(64, 3, (2, 2))(inputs)

my_seq = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=unet_layer)
```